# Display all posts from specific category and CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, wp-parse-args

Currently, we are getting all posts from a specific category using the following:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post'),
    'cat' => 1247,
    'posts_per_page' => 4
);
```

What we'd like to do is get all posts from cat 1247 and also from custom post type 'videos', such as:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array('post', 'videos'),
    'cat' => 1247,
    'posts_per_page' => 4
 );
```

However, as none of the posts in 'videos' are from category '1247', it's only showing posts from '1247', however I can't seem to find a category for posts in video?

How would we go about achieving what we need to achieve?

Comment: You won't be able to do this in a single query. As you found out, you are limiting the query by including the `cat` parameter. Edit: you might be able to do this by using `category__not_in` instead of `cat`, but then you'd have to add all of the other category ids to that list - might be hard if you have a bunch of categories. The other solution is to update the custom `video` post type to use the same categories and assign all of them that particular category - that also may not be feasible.

Comment: @disinfor `category__not_in` might be a shout as I don't have too many categories. Will give it a go.